# How to toggle click event using SDL?

Tags: c++, click, toggle, sdl

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- When user clicks in the game, the tile that the user clicks on will display a border
- If user clicks again (anywhere) the border goes away

What I Have so far:

- When user clicks in the game, border appears around selected tile

What I can't seem to figure out (I've tried everything I can think of)

- How to get the border to go away after another click

About my code:

I have a MouseInput class that checks if the left mouse button was pressed. I'm using boolean variables to try to toggle a variable that will display the tile border (if clicked) or not display the border (if clicked again). The code I have will allow the border to display but I can't get it to go away on another click. I can't really show all the things I tried (been trying this for 2 days and can't remember what I did lol).  This is a sumary of my code so far:

```
bool toggle; // Set to false in constructor
bool justPressed; // Set to false in constructor
bool justReleased; // Set to false in constructor

void Mouse::Update() // My custom mouse class Updating function (updates position, etc)
{
    input.Update(); // My MouseInput class Updating function.

    if (input.Left() && !toggle) // input.Left() checks if left mouse was pressed. True if it is pressed down, and false if it's not pressed.
    {
        // So we have pressed the mouse
        justPressed = true;
        justReleased = false;
        printf("UGH FML");
    }
    else if (!input.Left()) // So the mouse has been released (or hasn't clicked yet)
    {
        justPressed = false;
        justReleased = true;
    }

    if (justPressed)
    {
        toggle = true;
    }
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of to get toggle back to false. And now my brain is hurting. There's probably a real simple solution but I can't wrap my head around it. Suggestions?

Comment: Something like `if(event) border = !border;`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the following code block:

```
if (input.Left() && toggle) { //mouse is pressed and toggle is already true
    toggle = false;
}
```

You should also remove the following block of code, because it will set toggle to true if you pressed, regardless of if toggle was already true:

```
if (justPressed) {
    toggle = true;
}
```

Instead, you can set the toggle directly inside the if corresponding to the initial click:

```
if (input.Left() && !toggle) { //mouse is pressed and toggle is false
    toggle = true;
}
```

As mentioned by sp2danny, together those two blocks can be simplified to:

```
if (input.Left()) { //mouse is pressed
    toggle = !toggle;
}
```